# Using VPN in objective C once user is connected to VPN with Anyconnect,F5 BIG-IP Edge

Tags: iphone, ios, vpn

I am exploring the possibility of communicating with server that requires VPN connection outside of corporate network using iOS enabled device. I found out that I can connect to VPN using proprietary apps of Cisco, F5, Juniper etc. Assuming that user has successfully connected to VPN using these apps, can I directly communicate(call web service) from my iOS app? I know that Safari can directly communicate with server requiring VPN connection once user establish connection using one of apps I mentioned.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that there could be unique circumstances that cause problems, but in my experience I have found that this works just fine. I have an app that interacts with SOAP services running on servers within our corporate intranet. Once I have established a VPN connection using network-specific clients (I've used both Cisco and Juniper clients) I am able to use NSURLConnection and other iOS API's to connect to those servers.